# Mean of y value in vertical bin

Tags: python, numpy, binning

So I have Stock market data (date from 0 onwards, & a close price) and with this I use numpy.fft to calculate the fast fourier transform, and corresponding frequencies, and then have these in the form of a zipped list, 'FFT,Frequency'. I have the Frequency values separated into vertical logarithmic bins using:

```
logbins = np.logspace(Min(logX),max(logX),numbins=10, base=10.0
```

I then digitize the Frequency values into these bins and use:

```
for k in range(1,len(freqlogbins)):
    mean_freq.append(np.mean(Tfreq2[freqdig==k]))
```

Which works fine, however I need to also somehow work out the mean of the `y` values in each bin.

I imagine it is somehow possible referring to the `x` values in the `ZippedList[0,i]`, and the `y` values as `ZippedList[1,i]`

but can't quite work out how.

Here is an example of copyable code:

```
import numpy as np

T_date0=np.arange(0,400)
T_price=np.random.uniform(100,400, size=400)

T_fft=np.fft.fft(T_price)
Tfreq=np.fft.fftfreq(T_date0.shape[-1])
```

I then Eradicate any negative frequency values and the corresponding fft values using:

```
Tfreq2=[]
T_fft2=[]
for i in range(len(Tfreq)):                             
    if Tfreq[i]>0:
        Tfreq2.append(Tfreq[i])
        T_fft2.append(T_fft[i])       
T_fft_absSq=(np.absolute(T_fft2))**2
logTFAS=np.log10(T_fft_absSq)
logTfreq=np.log10(Tfreq2)

numbins=10
logbins=np.logspace((min(logTfreq)-0.00000001),(max(logTfreq)+0.00000001),num=numbins, base=10.0) #The +/-0.00000001 are so that the endpoints lie in the bin intervals.

Tfreq2=np.array(Tfreq2)
TFAS=np.array(T_fft_absSq)

freqdig=np.digitize(Tfreq2,logbins)
mean_freq=[]
mean_fft=[]
for k in range(1,len(logbins)):
mean_freq.append(np.mean(Tfreq2[freqdig==k]))

Fourier=zip(logTfreq,logTFAS)
##This is where I need to work out the mean of the y values, in the vertical bins
```

Here is what the data looks like, where the black dashed lines represent the bins, and the dashed yellow lines represent the mean of the x values in each bin. The blue line is a 2st order polynomial fit.

Obviously with random data it will look a little different to the link I posted below, but it gives an idea.

[image: Diagrammatic representation]

Comment: Can you write down a copy-paste-runnable example that populates all the variables (fake/random data is fine) and imports the modules you are using? For example, we don't know what `Tfreq2` and `freqdig` are.

Comment: cheers, have edited with a clearer description

Answer (score 1):

I was overthinking everything....

I was able to calculate the y value averages in a very similar way, using the frequency binning as such:

```
for k in range(1,len(logbins)):
    mean_freq.append(np.mean(np.array(logTfreq)[freqdig==k]))
    mean_fft.append(np.mean(np.array(logTFAS)[freqdig==k]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your asking for but maybe np.digitize will help:

```
import numpy as np
d = np.random.random(1000)
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
dig = np.digitize(d, bins)
binmean = [d[dig == i].mean() for i in range(1, len(bins))]

print binmean
```

Comment: That works well for calculating the mean frequency in each bin, which is what is plotted as a dashed yellow vertical line, but I need to calculate the mean FFT value in the bin